# Java arrays always equal

Tags: java, arrays, hyperlink, zero

I have an two-dimensional array number2 . I set it equal to number2copy with number2copy = number2
Then, I call a method Zeroed passing it the 2d array ToBeZeroed. This method fills the array with 0s, and I know it works. It returns ToBeZeroed full of zeros. But, when I put number2 = ToBeZeroed;
number2copy is also filled with zeros. How can I break up these things so a change in one does not cause a change in the other? They are unrelated arrays, so they need to be handled separately

Comment: How about posting the actual code?

Comment: why on earth would you write an english description of the code instead of just posting the code itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is not C++. You're copying the reference to the array attributed to the first dimension, not the array object and array sub-objects. You need to use `number2copy = (int[][])deepCopy(number2);`, which will perform a deep array copy which is appropriate for your needs, including copies of second dimension arrays contained within. Substitute `int[][]` for the 2D array datatype used which you didn't tell us about :) Additionally, to check if one object is equal to another, `==` will check the reference to the first dimension array of a 2D array, which is probably not what you want. For deep checking, use `Arrays.deepEquals(number2, number2copy);`, which should work fine.

Deep copy source code:

```
public static Object deepCopy(Object src)
{
    int srcLength = Array.getLength(src);
    Class srcComponentType = src.getClass().getComponentType();

    Object dest = Array.newInstance(srcComponentType, srcLength);

    if (srcComponentType.isArray())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(src); i++)
            Array.set(dest, i, deepCopy(Array.get(src, i)));
    }
    else
    {
        System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 0, srcLength);
    }

    return dest;
}
```

See [here](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) for a short explanation.

*Edit: I only just noticed that he said 2D array, so modified answer appropriately :)*

Answer (score 1):

> I set it equal to number2copy with number2copy = number2

At this point, and from then on (unless you assign a different value to either of those references) `number2copy` and `number2` point to *the same array*.  When you change the array via one reference, the changes are visible via the other one.

> How can I break up these things so a change in one does not cause a change in the other? They are unrelated arrays, so they need to be handled separately

Well, if they are unrelated arrays then you should not do `number2copy = number2` ... because that makes them the same array.

---

If you want to zero a 2-D array, you need to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < toBeZeroed.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < toBeZeroed[i].length; j++) {
        toBeZeroed[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

If you want to copy a 2-D array to another one, you need to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < from[i].length; j++) {
        to[i][j] = from[i][j];
    }
}
```

(This assumes that the `from` and `to` arrays have the same dimensions, there are no null subarrays, etcetera)

You may be able to find a 3rd-party library that zeros / copies arrays in the way you require.  However, while you are learning it will do you good to implement these yourself by hand, to help you get a clear mental model about Java works; e.g. reference assignment, what a 2-D array really is, etc ...

---

Beware of using `clone` to copy a 2-D (or more) array:

- It creates a new array object, where you seem to want to copy the values in one existing array to another existing array.
- It only performs a shallow copy; i.e. the new array will share the subarrays of the original, and you'll end up in the situation you are currently trying to avoid where changing one array affects the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are `Object`s and thus have *reference semantics*. That is to say, the assignment operration `x = y;` *aliases* and both `x` and `y` now refer to the same actual object.

(The opposite of that is *value semantics*, whereby the value of `y` gets *copied* to the distinct value `x`; primitive types such as `int` have value semantics.)

You will need to make an explicit `new` array and copy the data over.

---

The distinction between value and reference semantics is one of the most important aspects of the Java type system.